# WPF: How to get Binding.Converter

Tags: wpf, datagrid, converters

I create DataGrid Columns with Binding (where i is a Int value):

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
{
   Header = i.ToString(),
   Binding = CreateBinding(i),
});

private Binding CreateBinding(int num)
{
   Binding bind = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", num));         
   bind.Converter = new CellValueConverter();
   return bind;
}
```

In the CreateBinding method I have an access to bind.Converter property. 
 I need to call Converter.Convert() method in some handler, but there is no Converter property when I try to access it:

```
(dataGrid.Columns[clm] as DataGridTextColumn).Binding."no Converter property!"
```

How can I get my CellValueConverter which was created for particular Column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.binding(VS.100).aspx) property on `DataGridBoundColumn` (and `DataGridTextColumn`) actually returns a `BindingBase` instance, not a `Binding`.  `BindingBase` doesn't support converters.

You should be able to try to cast:

```
var binding = (dataGrid.Columns[clm] as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding;
if(binding != null)
{
    IValueConverter converter = binding.Converter; // Will work here
 }
```